# converting array with single value into string value in JOLT

Tags: jolt

**Input json :**

```
{
  "rating": "5",
  "quality": [
    "No"
  ]
}
```

**Jolt Spec :**

```
[
  {
    "operation": "modify-overwrite-beta",
    "spec": {
      "quality": {
        "0": "=toString"
      }
    }
  }
]
```

**Current Output:**

```
{
  "rating" : "5",
  "quality" : [ "No" ]
}
```

**Expected Output :**

```
{
  "rating" : "5",
  "quality" : "No"
}
```

please guide me with proper solution, how can I get String value as excepted

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you need only the first object of the quality array, then use `"0": "quality"`, or if it should be generic then use `"*": "quality"`.

But when you use the `"*": "quality"`, if the input json has more than one value in the quality array, then output also, will be having quality as array.

```
[
  {
    "operation": "shift",
    "spec": {
      "rating": "rating",
      "quality": {
        "*": "&1"
      }
    }
  }
]
```